# Playing Two Videos in a Single Window in Gstreamer

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer

***UPDATED::***
I would like to play two videos in a single window from .ts file.

I have used below pipeline:

```
 gst-launch-1.0 \
   filesrc location=new1.ts \
     ! tsdemux name=demuxer \
   demuxer. \
     ! queue ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 \
     ! videobox border-alpha=0 right=-640 \
     ! videomixer name=mix ! videoconvert \
     ! autovideosink \
   demuxer. \
     ! queue ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 \
     ! videobox border-alpha=0 left=-640 \
     ! autovideoconvert ! mix.
```

But the Problem is, if one of the video caught then automatically second video would went into paused state, then whole pipeline is in paused state. And the playing window is doesn't responding.

How to resolve this?

Or Is there any other way to play two videos in a single window without occurring above problem?